# Change the text of the radio button dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, radio-button

I have a scenario of having a series of radio buttons with a name of the payment method. I need to change that text on load of the page. For Example.

```
<label class="radio-inline">
  <div class="iradio_square-blue">
    <input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="Paypal">
    <ins></ins>
  </div>
  Paypal India
</label>
```

In the above code sample I need to change the **"Paypal India"** to **"Paypal Global"** via javascript We do not have id to the radio button only way to target is via value of the radio button which in the case above is paypal.

Can anyone help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Paypal India` is a TextNode inside the label. Here's how to find and replace: https://jsfiddle.net/62r1fa5L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look at the childNodes

```js
const label = document.querySelector("[name=paymentmethod][value=Paypal]")
  .closest("label");
[...label.childNodes].forEach(node => {
  let text = node.textContent;
  if (text && text.includes("India")) {
    node.textContent = text.replace("India", "Global");
  }
});
```

```html
<label class="radio-inline">
  <div class="iradio_square-blue">
    <input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="Paypal">
    <ins></ins>
  </div>
  Paypal India
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here for your reference. I think it will be helpful.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const labels = document.getElementsByClassName('radio-inline');
  if (labels.length) {
    let label = labels[0];
    label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace(/Paypal India/, 'Paypal Global');
  }
});
```

Comment: This will not work. It will wipe the contents of the label. See my answer for the correct way - test it please